# Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'DisplayTitle' is not a valid attribute of element 'WebPartZone'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint WebPartZone declared on an ASP.NET page.

This is not the same as the `<asp:WebPartZone/>` control.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages"
    Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone ID="LeftNavZone" runat="server" DisplayTitle="loc:LeftNavZone">
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

Visual Studio 2010 displays the following "Message" in the Error List window:

> Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'DisplayTitle' is not a valid attribute of element 'WebPartZone'.

When it most certainly is...

[WebPartZone.DisplayTitle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpartzone.displaytitle%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

And this isn't an issue of class confusion, as DisplayTitle is also a property of the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartZone` control (inherited from `WebPartZoneBase`):

[WebPartZoneBase.DisplayTitle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartzonebase.displaytitle%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

So what gives? And how can I get rid of this message?

There's one of these messages for every page in my project when I have it open... certainly annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisplayTitle` is read only...

It needs to be set via the `HeaderText` property.